# Photoshop pencil tool missing edge pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pencil

In photoshop, if i click in 1 place to draw a dot, then hold shift and click anywhere else to draw a straight line, a line is drawn but with missing pixels along the edge. This is extremely annoying as i have to go back and manually fix it. Is there any way to fix this?

[image: missing pixels along line edge]

Answer (score 4):

Goto Windows > Brush Settings > Brush Tip Shape. Set the spacing to the minimum.